# docker swarm database connection reset by peer

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, docker-swarm

I am running a spring boot application with docker swarm and I use postgres for database. When I run both of them as docker service, database connection fails consistently and randomly (as you can see on the timestamp) as the log says:

2017-10-26T**17:14:15**.200415747Z app-db.1.1ayo6h8ro1og@scw-c2964a    | LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

2017-10-26T**17:43:36**.481718562Z app-db.1.1ayo6h8ro1og@scw-c2964a    | LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

2017-10-26T**17:43:56**.954152654Z app-db.1.1ayo6h8ro1og@scw-c2964a    | LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

2017-10-26T**17:44:17**.434171472Z app-db.1.1ayo6h8ro1og@scw-c2964a    | LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

2017-10-26T**17:49:04**.154174253Z app-db.1.1ayo6h8ro1og@scw-c2964a    | LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer

I couldn't understand or discover the reason for this. I'd appreciate any ideas.

edit:

we realized that, when testing the application, it also throws error like this:

SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 937517ms

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've got the same error deploying Docker Swarm stack of Spring Boot app and PostgreSQL. After battling with this for about a week, I've figured out that issue was in firewall dropping connections between containers because of inactivity. Quick answer, run following cmd on linux machine:

```
sudo sysctl -w \
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=600 \
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl=60 \
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes=3
```

As well, I've included following tomcat connection pool properties:

```
tomcat:
  max-active: 10
  initial-size: 5
  max-idle: 8
  min-idle: 5
  test-on-borrow: true
  test-while-idle: true
  test-on-return: false
  test-on-connect: true
  validation-query: SELECT 1
  validation-interval: 30000
  max-wait: 30000
  min-evictable-idle-time-millis: 60000
  time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 5000
  remove-abandoned: true
  remove-abandoned-timeout: 60
```

Solution came from this blogpost: [DEALING WITH NODENOTAVAILABLE EXCEPTIONS IN ELASTICSEARCH](https://blog.trifork.com/2015/04/08/dealing-with-nodenotavailableexceptions-in-elasticsearch/)

Comment: I will try this as soon as possible.Thanks for your help!

Comment: hi, i tried the solution and i only applied the first part. it's been up since yesterday and not failed. i guess it works :) thanks a lot!

Comment: Containers running kernel 4.13 or later will no longer inherit `tcp_keepalive_time` from the host (source: https://success.docker.com/article/ipvs-connection-timeout-issue), so this approach will no longer work with newer containers.  However, as of Docker 19.03 there is a `sysctl` option that can be supplied to services (e.g. in a compose file).  This can be used to set the above flags directly in the containers without messing with the host.  https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#sysctls

Answer (score 6):

There is another way to prevent closing idle connection. The problem is related to default swarm service discovery which closes the idle connection after 15 minutes.
Explicit specified the `dnsrr` [endpoint mode](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#endpoint_mode) resolves the problem, e.g.:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  foo-service:
    image: example/foo-service:latest
    hostname: foo-service
    networks:
      - foo_network
    deploy:
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
      # ...

networks:
  foo_network:
    external: true
    driver: overlay
```

Comment: Amazing. I haven't found anything about this behavior in Docker docs. How did you figure it out? Maybe, we should submit a PR into Docker docs?